# Javascript onclick event to write new div

Tags: javascript, onclick, document.write

Can't seem to figure out why this isn't working. I have an onclick event on a href that should fire a javascript function that writes a new div. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm pretty sure my problem is with the link, not the function.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Blah</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .box {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 5;
        width:100%;
        height:100%; 
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
        padding:25px 10px 25px 10px;
    }
    .content {
        z-index: 1;
        padding: 25px 15px 10px 15px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">     
        function test() {
            document.write("<div class='box'>Box Test</div>");  
        }
    </script>
    <h1>Test Page</h1>

    <div class="content">
        <a onclick="javascript:test" href="#">Test Test Test</a>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: horrible JS, btw.. you should **call** that function i.e. `test()`

Comment: This is not the right way to add HTML to a page.

Comment: You two are so helpful </sarcasm>

Comment: Mmmm.. y isn't helpful telling you that js code is horrible? +, to call that test function u really forgot to put `()` .. see here http://jsfiddle.net/hHGnL/ 
...And, inside David Thomas' answer u'll find the right way to solve a problem like this. ..have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

One approach, and I've moved away from the in-line JavaScript, in order that a: the JavaScript/behaviour's less intrusive, and b: so there's less need to look through every element in order to affect/change what happens:

```
var d = document,
    as = d.getElementsByTagName('a');

function test(elem,evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    var div = d.createElement('div'),
        tN = d.createTextNode(elem.firstChild.nodeValue),
        b = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    div.appendChild(tN);
    b.insertBefore(div,elem.parentNode);
}

for (var i=0,len=as.length;i<len;i++){
    as[i].onclick = function(e){
        test(this,e);
    };
}​
```

With the following HTML:

```
<h1>Test Page</h1>

<div class="content">
    <a href="#">Test Test Test</a>
</div>​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/58VrE/1/).

To try and explain [Mathletics' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301243/javascript-onclick-event-to-write-new-div/10301670#comment-13256777), the problem is that you're using `document.write()`, this certainly writes to the document. Unfortunately it *over-writes* the document itself; so the page contents are replaced entirely.

References:

- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement).
- [`document.createTextNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createTextNode).
- [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.write).
- [`element.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.appendChild).
- [`element.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName).
- [`element.firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.firstChild).
- [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault).
- [`node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.insertBefore)
- [`node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document_Object_Model_(DOM)/Node.nextSibling).
- [`node.nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nodeValue).

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Blah</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .box {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 5;
        width:100%;
        height:100%; 
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
        padding:25px 10px 25px 10px;
    }
    .content {
        z-index: 1;
        padding: 25px 15px 10px 15px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">     
        function test() {
            document.write("<div class='box'>Box Test</div>");  
        }
    </script>
    <h1>Test Page</h1>

    <div class="content">
        <a onclick="test()" href="javascript:;">Test Test Test</a>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

see

```
<a onclick="javascript:test" href="#">Test Test Test</a>
```

updated to

```
<a onclick="test()" href="javascript:;">Test Test Test</a>
```

missing paranthesis

Note: I prefer to use "javascript:;" instead of "#" inorder to prevent page scrolling top

Comment: doesn't matter. It can be like "#". I put "javascript:;" inorder to prevent page from scrolling top.You can also use "#"

Answer (score -1):

```
<a onclick="javascript:test**();**" href="#">Test Test Test</a>
```

hope that helps, martin

Comment: I guess he was just trying to put emphasis (make them bold) on the parenthesis. he's just new!

Comment: @Adriano: yeah right. the code editor is quite confusing :) thanks for understanding!